# New Rails GraphQL installation can't load /graphiql; crashes with "Invalid or incomplete introspection result. Ensure that you are passing..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

steps to reproduce:
`rails new HelloGraphQLWorld`

install Gems

```
gem 'graphiql-rails', group: :development
gem 'graphql'
```

run `bundle install`

then run graphql installer: `rails generate graphql:install`

• notice several files are generated here for you by the installer
• Start rails server `rails s`
• Open /graphiql in browser window

It crashes (cannot open correctly) with:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid or incomplete introspection result. Ensure that you are passing \"data\" property of introspection response and no \"errors\" was returned alongside: {}.",
  "stack": "Error: Invalid or incomplete introspection result. Ensure that you are passing \"data\" property of introspection response and no \"errors\" was returned alongside: {}.\n    at devAssert (webpack-internal:///../../../node_modules/graphql/jsutils/devAssert.mjs:7:11)\n    at buildClientSchema (webpack-internal:///../../../node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildClientSchema.mjs:41:266)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./components/GraphiQL.tsx:1133:57)"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens if your APP NAME is not correctly TitleCase..

ironically, the "QL" in the App name is the problem, because the generator genreates code with HelloGraphQLWorldSchema but the Zietwork framework (part of Rails) is expecting this to be correctly title cased as HelloGraphQlWorldSchema

both the file definition `app/graphql/hello_graph_ql_world_schema.rb` and in the graphQL controller too

`// graphql_controller.rb`

```
    result = HelloGraphQLWorldSchema.execute(query, variables: variables, context: context, operation_name: operation_name)
```

should be

```
    result = HelloGraphQlWorldSchema.execute(query, variables: variables, context: context, operation_name: operation_name)
```

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "uninitialized constant GraphqlController::HelloGraphQLWorldSchema\nDid you mean?  HelloGraphQlWorldSchema",
      "backtrace": [
        "/Users/jason/Work/_LEARNING/GraphQL/HelloGraphQLWorld/app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:15:in `execute'",
        "/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'",
        "/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:214:in `process_action'",
        "/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:53:in `process_action'",
        "/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-7.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'",
        "/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-
```

[image]

Alternatively, if your app has correct titlecasing this should not apply to you.